# Extract suburb name from address string in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of addresses (property) from which I need to extract just the suburb name. I have another table (suburbs) that contains all of the suburb names.

I'm having a problem with the multi-word suburb names, where a match is found on one, and both words. I need it to match with the longest suburb name, eg. an address with "North Bondi" should only match to suburb "North Bondi" and not suburb "Bondi".

I've found some examples online that use the MAX function in the join but Bigquery won't let me use that function in the join.

Would appreciate if someone could please suggest corrections, or provide guidance on other solutions (eg. sorting the suburb table and retrieving only one result?) Thank you!

Table: property

| address |
| --- |
| 12 Smith Street Surry Hills NSW |
| 34 Jones Street Bondi NSW |
| 15 Sunny Road North Bondi NSW |

Table: suburbs

| suburb | state |
| --- | --- |
| Surry Hills | NSW |
| Bondi | NSW |
| North Bondi | NSW |

Current code used:

```
Select * from  ( SELECT p.address, s.suburb 
       FROM `property` p
       JOIN `suburbs` s
         ON INITCAP(p.address) LIKE CONCAT('%', INITCAP(s.suburb),' ', INITCAP(s.state), '%')
      GROUP BY p.address, s.suburb
   ) x
join `property` p
ON p.address = x.address
where p.address is not null;
```

Actual result:

| address | suburb |
| --- | --- |
| 12 Smith Street Surry Hills NSW | Surry Hills |
| 34 Jones Street Bondi NSW | Bondi |
| 15 Sunny Road North Bondi NSW | Bondi |
| 15 Sunny Road North Bondi NSW | North Bondi |

Desired result:

| address | suburb |
| --- | --- |
| 12 Smith Street Surry Hills NSW | Surry Hills |
| 34 Jones Street Bondi NSW | Bondi |
| 15 Sunny Road North Bondi NSW | North Bondi |

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  v1.address,
        string_agg(v1.addr_part, " ") as suburb,
from    (
          select  t.address,
                  addr_part,
          from    property t
          cross join unnest(split(t.address, " ")) addr_part WITH OFFSET AS ofst
          where   ofst > 2
          qualify row_number() over(partition by t.address order by ofst desc) > 1
        ) v1
group by v1.address
;
```

But! This approach assumes:

1. The first 3 words in every address are not belong to suburb name;
2. Every state is one word.

Answer (score 0):

> I've found some examples online that use the MAX function in the join but Bigquery won't let me use that function in the join.

Using a window function Instead of a **MAX** function,

```sql
Select * from  ( SELECT p.address, s.suburb 
       FROM `property` p
       JOIN `suburbs` s
         ON INITCAP(p.address) LIKE CONCAT('%', INITCAP(s.suburb),' ', INITCAP(s.state), '%')
   ) x
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY address ORDER BY LENGTH(suburb) DESC) = 1
```

##### Query results:

| address | suburb |
| --- | --- |
| 12 Smith Street Surry Hills NSW | Surry Hills |
| 15 Sunny Road North Bondi NSW | North Bondi |
| 34 Jones Street Bondi NSW | Bondi |

Comment: Thanks Jaytiger, that works for me. I think Mikhail's answer is a little simpler (at least for my level) but interesting use of qualify and rank which I'll definitely use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT p.address, 
  STRING_AGG(s.suburb ORDER BY LENGTH(s.suburb) DESC LIMIT 1) suburb
FROM `property` p
JOIN `suburbs` s
ON INITCAP(p.address) LIKE CONCAT('%', INITCAP(s.suburb),' ', INITCAP(s.state), '%')
GROUP BY p.address
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I think this is the simplest solution. I would mark this as the accepted answer though it appears I don't have enough of a 'reputation' to do so.